# Adding CSS makes content stay visible in Bootstrap tab?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a class "formbox" that when applied to the form makes the content stay visible. But when you remove it, it acts as expected. I tried to remove each css rule individually and brute force test it, but that didn't isolate anything...Any thoughts? I apologize if this is a stupid question! I'm still somewhat new to front-end!

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
a{color:#fff;}
.formbox{
  width:100%;

}

.formbox p{
  margin:0;
  padding:1px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.formbox input{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.formbox input[type="email"],
.formbox input[type="text"],
.formbox input[type="password"]
{
background-color : #161925;
border:none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #F1D302;
height:40px;
}
.formbox input[type="email"]:focus,
.formbox input[type="text"]:focus,
.formbox input[type="password"]:focus
{
border-bottom: 2px solid #FDFFFC;
}
textarea, input, button { outline: none; }

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus
{
  color:#161925;
  background-color : #F1D302 ;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>STEMuli</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/newuser.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <!--This is where the logo is-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <a name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()"><img src="#" class="img-fluid" width="200" height="400" alt="Responsive image">
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">  <h4>Type of User</h4></div>
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 red" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Student</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Teacher</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Corporation</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
<!--Start of first tab-->
<div class="formbox">
<form class="submission-form">
  <p>Name</p>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="Kylo Ren">
  <p>Email</p>
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="knightsofRen@dark.com">
  <p>Password</p>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;">
  <p>Confirm Password</p>
  <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;">
  <p>Grade</p>
  <select class="selectpicker">
    <optgroup label="Elementary">
      <option>1st Grade</option>
      <option>2nd Grade</option>
      <option>3rd Grade</option>
      <option>4th Grade</option>
      <option>5th Grade</option>
      <option>6th Grade</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Middle">
      <option>7th Grade</option>
      <option>8th Grade</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="High">
      <option>9th Grade</option>
      <option>10th Grade</option>
      <option>1th Grade</option>
      <option>12th Grade</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <p>Date of Birth</p>
  <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" id="student-dob" name="student-dob">
  <p>Dream Job</p>
  <input type="text" id="dream-job" name="dream-job" data-require-pair="#choice-dream-job">

  <p>Role Model (favorite athlete, actor, musician)</p>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">

  <p>Dream University</p>
  <input type="text" id="dream-university" name="dream-university" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">

  <p>Career Pathway/Industry</p>
  <input type="text" id="student-career" name="student-career" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">

  <p>Favorite Band/Company</p>
  <input type="text" id="student-favorite" name="student-favorite" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">

  <p>World problem you would like to solve</p>
  <input type="text" id="world-problem" name="world-problem" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
</form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="container">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
        <button class="button"><ahref="#" name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()">Submit</a></button>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </main>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/form.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does "acts as expected" mean?

Comment: When another tab is selected the previous active data should disappear and be taken place by the currently selected tab. In this case the ellipsis "...".

Comment: it's not your custom css that's the issue, you just have an unclosed div, which means your second and third tabs are actually nested inside your first tab.  add a `</div>` right before your second tab pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you missed a closing tag . So your first `tab-pane` wrap the other tab.

**Here is the working Snppet**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
a {
 color: #fff;
}
.formbox {
 width: 100%;
}
.formbox p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.formbox input {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.formbox input[type="email"], .formbox input[type="text"], .formbox input[type="password"] {
 background-color : #161925;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #F1D302;
 height: 40px;
}
.formbox input[type="email"]:focus, .formbox input[type="text"]:focus, .formbox input[type="password"]:focus {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #FDFFFC;
}
textarea, input, button {
 outline: none;
}
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
 color: #161925;
 background-color : #F1D302;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>STEMuli</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/newuser.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<!--This is where the logo is-->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center"> <a name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()"><img src="#" class="img-fluid" width="200" height="400" alt="Responsive image"> </a> </div>
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <h4>Type of User</h4>
</div>
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 red" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Student</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Teacher</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Corporation</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab"> 
            <!--Start of first tab-->
            <div class="formbox">
                <form class="submission-form">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="Kylo Ren">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="knightsofRen@dark.com">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;">
                    <p>Confirm Password</p>
                    <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;">
                    <p>Grade</p>
                    <select class="selectpicker">
                        <optgroup label="Elementary">
                        <option>1st Grade</option>
                        <option>2nd Grade</option>
                        <option>3rd Grade</option>
                        <option>4th Grade</option>
                        <option>5th Grade</option>
                        <option>6th Grade</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Middle">
                        <option>7th Grade</option>
                        <option>8th Grade</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="High">
                        <option>9th Grade</option>
                        <option>10th Grade</option>
                        <option>1th Grade</option>
                        <option>12th Grade</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    <p>Date of Birth</p>
                    <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" id="student-dob" name="student-dob">
                    <p>Dream Job</p>
                    <input type="text" id="dream-job" name="dream-job" data-require-pair="#choice-dream-job">
                    <p>Role Model (favorite athlete, actor, musician)</p>
                    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
                    <p>Dream University</p>
                    <input type="text" id="dream-university" name="dream-university" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
                    <p>Career Pathway/Industry</p>
                    <input type="text" id="student-career" name="student-career" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
                    <p>Favorite Band/Company</p>
                    <input type="text" id="student-favorite" name="student-favorite" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
                    <p>World problem you would like to solve</p>
                    <input type="text" id="world-problem" name="world-problem" data-require-pair="#choice-last-name">
                </form>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- missed closing tag -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer class="container">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
        <button class="button"><ahref="#" name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()">Submit</a></button>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== --> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/form.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```